# constructor c7 in class c7 cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, class

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxYQ3.png)
I have three classes c6,c7 and c8 as given below:

```
public class c6{
private String name;
private int age;
public c6() {
    //default constructor
}
public c6(String name,int age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
public void show(){
    System.out.println("Name :"+name);
    System.out.println("Age :"+age);
}}
```

here is my class c7

```
public class c7 extends c6{
private double salary;
public c7() {
    //default constructor
}
public c7(String name,int age,double salary) {
    super(name,age);
    this.salary = salary;
}
public void show(){
    super.show();
    System.out.println("Salary :"+salary);
}}
```

here is my class c8:

```
public class c8 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    c7 ob1 = new c7("akhil",12,9000.00);
    c7 ob2 = new c7("akhil",12);

    ob1.show();
    ob2.show();
}}
```

I am trying to inherit the contents of c6 into c7
and the error  I am getting is

```
c8.java:4: error: constructor c7 in class c7 cannot be applied to given types;
            c7 ob1 = new c7("akhil",12,9000.00);
                     ^
 required: no arguments
found: String,int,double
```

reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

i get the same error for `c8.java:5`

Comment: Are you 100% sure? I'm getting `error: no suitable constructor found for c7(String,int)` when creating `ob2`.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but unless there's some pathological reason not to, give your classes names with meaning.

Comment: may be try to public | protected the name and age in c6

Comment: @SyedBaryalay Why? How is that related? Or a good idea?

Comment: just try it, coz every thing seems fine in the code

Comment: @SyedBaryalay ... There's zero issues with accessing `name` or `age`, the issue is with the ctor (and not convinced the problem being reported is the actual problem). Trying things at random... meh.

Comment: Yes, `c7` has no constructor that takes 2 arguments. So, what do you expect to happen? That the constructor with 3 arguments is called?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn The problem is that it *does* have a ctor that takes three, which is what the OP is calling, hence BackSlash's comment.

Comment: @DaveNewton `c7 ob2 = new c7("akhil",12);`. I count 2.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn `c8.java:6: error: constructor c7 in class c7 cannot be applied to given types;
            c7 ob1 = new c7("akhil",12,9000.00);` is the error reported by the OP. But good job counting.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I count two as well, but that isn't the line the compiler/interpreter is complaining about.

Comment: `public c7(String name, int age) {
  super(name,age);
 }`added these lines in class c7 but it didn't give any errors but o/p is `Name :akhil
Age :12
Salary :9000.0
Name :akhil
Age :12
Salary :0.0 `why is it so??

Comment: A class `String` hiding `java.lang.String`?